# angular httpclient post when returning 4xx error the error handler only contains OK, no json is parsed

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, error-handling

I have created a REST api in .net core 2.1 and an angular front end initially in 7 but upgraded to 8 recently.

I have several post endpoints that are used to create new items (questions, answers, users, applications etc) the endpoints will take a json object and then run some validation rules against them. If the rules succeed then the object is saved to the database, if it fails it returns the modelstate errors and a 422 (have also tried 400) error along with the json response for example
{"Address":["Please enter the address"],"TopLevelBudgetId":["Please select a top level budget"]}

However the error is always "OK"

.subscribe(
      () => {
        this.router.navigate([`/administration/users`]);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }));

in postman I can see the correct status code 422 and the json modelstate as shown above.

I have no idea where I have gone wrong whatsoever, followed various angular tutorials and have yet to find a solution.

I can see in the network tab of chrome tools that it first sends options and gets back a 204, this is because the sites locally on my machine are on different ports so it's handling CORS, and then it does the post correctly showing the 422 status code and the response.

Why do I only receive "OK" in the error handler

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you think this is Angular 8 related?

Comment: I don’t think so, it’s the reason I upgraded to 8 from 7 as had the exact same issue

Comment: I’m wondering if it’s something to do with the options request first as that does return 204 which I guess is the reason for the OK. I’d have thought that the HttpClient would handle this though and then parse the actual post. Do I need to handle this myself?

Comment: Share us your code which returns this json. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));`

Comment: Hi Tao 
when I try to log error.response.data I get 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
The error is just "OK" nothing else. This is contained in the second lambda to the subscribe as shown in the original post

Comment: could it be to do with the cors preflight checks, only my get methods are exempt from authentication. Everything looks correct on this front though, if I disable cors in my .net backend I get a cors error in the front end. It just seems as though the 204 response that the preflight returns before the post is attempted is what is returned in the error object instead of the json that is returned in the actual post method. Something is obviously amiss but I can't see what and it shouldn;t be this difficult.

Comment: feel free to close the question as I can't see how, presume it's because I'm a new member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it was a schoolboy error on my part. I have an interceptor that handles 401/403 authentication errors and redirects to the login page.

This was the part that was at fault, didn't realise I had this interceptor as it was added near to the beginning of the development

const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
return throwError(error);

altered to rethrow the exception

return throwError(err);